# Grep Pattern and the next word

Tags: grep

I have a text file with lines like this (only the last two strings matter):

```
1 sometext Pattern
2 sometext Pattern  5Asda5}  
3 sometext Pattern asd2-asd  
4 sometext Pattern a-d
5 sometext Pattern   foobar  
6 sometext Pattern {asd  
7 Pattern Pattern something 123asd  
8 Pattern sometext asd    
9 Pattern 5h{1,2}b
```

I need to find each line with "Pattern" as last word. A word is defined in this case as string with letters and hyphens. There can be leading spaces or spaces following a string (like this: Pattern\t\t\t\t\t$)

My take at this is

```
egrep  '(\bPattern\b +[^a-zA-Z\-]{2,} *$)|(\bPattern\b *$)' file.txt
```

to find all lines with Pattern followed by space(s) and a non-"word" at the end or with Pattern at the end.
But the first part does not work as intended. I need another way to find the non-words.

Could you show me a way to grep line 1,2,3,6,9 but not the rest?
 I like to stay away from awk as we did not cover it in class.

Comment: Yes that is correct, my output is only line 1

Comment: Please edit your original question with a sample output.

Comment: @hschou, the OP does say they want lines 1,2,3,6,9 (I also missed that initially).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\b`, in `grep` implementations that support it, is for the transition between a word character (alnum and underscore) and non-word character (or vise versa). So `\bPattern\b` would match in `foo-Pattern.bar` for instance.

If you're looking for a blank-delimited *Pattern* word, you can't use `\b`.

Here, it seems you're looking for a blank-delimited `Pattern` that is followed by a list of zero or more blank-delimited strings that have characters other than letters and `-`, so:

```
non_word='([^[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:][:alpha:]-][^[:blank:]]*)'
grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])Pattern([[:blank:]]+$non_word)*[[:blank:]]*$"
```

Comment: I used \bPattern\b because i know that there aren't any cases like you described, only something like aPattern or Patternn can happen.  I am not used to the [:expression:] format. Would be :blank: \t and :alpha: would be [a-zA-Z0-9]?

Comment: @JDizzle, `[:alpha:]` is a character class for all alphabetical characters in the locale. Change to `[:alnum:]` if you also want digits. Nowadays, there's no saying what `[a-zA-Z]` might include unless you're in the `C` locale. `[:blank:]` is all horizontal spacing characters. In the C locale, that's space and tab.

Comment: So far so good, the last thing i don't understand is why this part is necessary: non_word='([^[:blank:]]*, in the grep command we say that there may be leading blanks, so why we tell then there cant be leading blanks.  And why there is no + or * after [:alpha:]? why does the Pattern non_word repeat itself?

Comment: @JDizzle, It's not that _there can't be leading blanks_. It's that non-words are sequences of 0 or more (`*`) non-blanks (so can be letters, digits, anything except blanks) following by *one* of those characters that make non-words (so there is at least one) followed by zero or more non-blanks.

Comment: This pattern will accept anything that only has non-words (after the word "Pattern"), but all mixed content (words and non-words) like `sometext Pattern abcd word ow{ord` will be rejected. It is not clear from the OP description if that is valid or not, but interesting to know.

Comment: Yes this is the way it wanted it to be. In this text file i either need to count the lines where "Pattern" is the last or first "word" in a line, or where Pattern isn't the last word (for this i would use the -v option).